# Unable to map product features with catalog

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am able to insert values into `productfeature`, but these are not coming under `classification features`, instead those `productfeatures` available in `unclassified features` list by using below impex.

```
INSERT_UPDATE ProductFeature;classificationAttributeAssignment; product(code)[unique=true];qualifier;
value[translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ProductFeatureValueTranslator];
;product number;1008525794;product number;product number,HPE ProLiant ML10 Gen9 E3-1225;
```

Answer (score 0):

The classificationAttributeAssignment header expects a PK so I don't see how your impex would work. You should create a classAttributeAssignment it defines a field classificationClass in which you define the categorization for your feature(so your feature belongs somewhere so it does not float around).

For instance:

```
insert_update ClassAttributeAssignment;attributeType(itemtype(code),code)[unique=true];classificationAttribute(code,systemVersion(catalog(id),version))[forceWrite=true,allownull=true,unique=true];classificationClass(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code)[forceWrite=true,allownull=true,unique=true];comparable[allownull=true];description[lang=en];formatDefinition;listable[allownull=true];localized[allownull=true];mandatory[allownull=true];multiValued[allownull=true];position;range[allownull=true];searchable[allownull=true];systemVersion(catalog(id),version)[forceWrite=true,unique=true];unit(code,systemVersion(catalog(id),version))[unique=true];visibility(itemtype(code),code)
;ClassificationAttributeTypeEnum:boolean;IsCool:ExampleClassification:1.0;ExampleClassification:1.0:Search;TRUE;;;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;1;FALSE;FALSE;ExampleClassification:1.0;;ClassificationAttributeVisibilityEnum:visible
```

- ClassificationAttribute (the feature itself): `IsCool`
- SystemVersion (catalog for your classification classes):   `ExampleClassification:1.0`
- ClassificationClass (category bundeling the features): `Search`

So providing you created (for instance in the hMC) the `ExampleClassification` and gave it the version `1.0`(catalog->classification system) , the `IsCool` feature descriptor (feature list->feature descriptor) and in the `ExampleClassification` you created the `Search` classification class. If you assign the classification class to your product(supercategories), you should see the `IsCool` feature displayed for your product.

And assigning the value to the product with sku 100:

```
insert_update Product;code[unique=true,allownull=true];catalog(id)[allownull=true];catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true];@IsCool[system='ExampleClassification',version='1.0',translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeTranslator]
;100;Default;Default:Staged;TRUE
```

Or you can also assign the value using the `ProductFeature`:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ProductFeature;classificationattributeAssignment(classificationAttribute(code,systemVersion(catalog(id),version)),systemVersion(catalog(id),version),classificationClass(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code))[unique=true]; product(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code)[unique=true];value[translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ProductFeatureValueTranslator]
;IsCool:ExampleClassification:1.0:ExampleClassification:1.0:ExampleClassification:1.0:Search;Default:Staged:100;boolean,TRUE
```

Comment: hi, this is not working, [code, catalog, catalogVersion, @product number] ,1=ValueEntry('1008525794'=1008525794,unresolved=false,ignore=false), 2=ValueEntry('hpeCatalog'=8796093121112,unresolved=false,ignore=false), 3=ValueEntry('hpeCatalog:Staged'=hpeCatalog/Staged(8796093186649),unresolved=false,ignore=false), 4=ValueEntry('HPE ProLiant ML10'=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false), 5=ValueEntry(''=null,unresolved=null,ignore=false)}]

Comment: I've edited my answer with an impex that adds the value using the ProductFeature header. In your original question you should change the header for the classificationAttributeAssignment like in my version also you must assign a value using: type, value. Like i did boolean,FALSE. The problem with your features being unclassified is due to the classificationAttributeAssignment.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above impex but it is not working.

Comment: INSERT_UPDATE ProductFeature;classificationAttributeAssignment(classificationAttribute(code,systemVersion(catalog(id),version)),systemVersion(catalog(id),version),classificationClass(catalogversion(catalog(id),version),code))[unique=true];Product(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code)[unique=true];language;qualifier;value[translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ProductFeatureValueTranslator]

Comment: ;prodlongname:hpeClassification:1.0:hpeClassification:1.0:hpeClassification:1.0:CoreInformation;hpeCatalog:Staged:860185-035;ww-en;prodlongname;String,HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen9 E5-2630v4 1P 16GB-R P440ar 8SFF 2x500W PS Server/TV